# How to set grafana's radar graph(InfluxDB)?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, radar-chart

I have a struggle to present my data with radar graph plugin for Grafana. My goal is to obtain something like in this picture:

[image]

Single branch represents an object. Points on the branch represent object's properties.

Can anybody support me with a simple instruction?

Edit 1.

I've tried to set it like it is in [the link](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/snuids-radar-panel).

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdIaB.png).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which kind of radar plugin are you using. Did you try https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/snuids-radar-panel and did you read plugin documentation ?

Comment: I've tried to set it like it is in your link before but without success > Edit 1

Answer (score 0):

Snuids radar seems to be slightly broken in the latest versions of Grafana and InfluxDB.

To get the above working (albeit not 100%) you need to use a time-series format.

See https://github.com/snuids/grafana-radar-panel/issues/22 for the issue.